# Como fazer Texto 3D com CSS

Tags: css, css3, 3d

Existe algum maneira de chegar nesse resultado apenas com CSS?

Fazer um tipo de efeito 3D no texto panes com CSS? Tipo a imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    background-color: #880000;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Text</h1>
```

Comment: Com direito a mouseover: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmeqmm  - Tirado [daqui](https://www.bypeople.com/css-3d-text-shadow-effect/)

Comment: @Bacco rapaz impressionante a qualidade da sombra movimentando, foda d+! OBS, que site massa, estou derretendo lá nos CSS Snippet, tem muito coisa interessante achei esse exemplo aqui muito legal tb https://codepen.io/flowuhh/pen/YjQKeZ Obrigado por compartilhar mestre 

Comment: @Bacco eu reparei que esse seu exemplo é scss mas acho que seria muito interessante de transformar isso numa resposta possívelmente incluindo tanto o scss como o css compilado. Achei o exemplo fantástico.

Comment: @Isac no codepen dá pra ver o SCSS compilado em CSS. Eu não achei relevante como resposta, pois a técnica é a mesma das duas respostas já existentes, foi só uma questão de maior "dedicação artística" de quem desenvolveu, até porque o objetivo era diferente de simplesmente explicar como fazer. Só quis por aqui como complemento mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O segredo para fazer um texto 3D está na propriedade `text-shadow` do CSS. Veja o conceito da propriedade:

> A propriedade text-shadow acrescenta sombras ao texto. Ela aceita uma
>   lista de sombras separadas por vírgula que serão aplicados ao texto e
>   ao text-decorations do elemento.
>
> Cada sombra é especificada como um deslocamento do texto, juntamente
>   com valores opcionais de cor e raio de desfoque.

Antes de vermos um exemplo já vou avisando que sem dúvidas o mais chato de tudo é combinar as cores para aplicar um efeito legal no texto, e é interessante sempre ir editando para ver o efeito pelas ferramentas do desenvolvedor (famoso inspecionar).

No exemplo abaixo coloquei em um tonalidade mais forte, para visualizar melhor as sombras aplicadas, mas, caso queira, é só trocar os tons. A ideia era deixar o mais parecido possível com sua imagem (ao menos o estilo).

```css
body {
    background-color: #880000;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow:  
      1px -1px 0 #2f5d87, 
      2px -2px 0 #2e5a83, 
      3px -3px 0 #2d5880, 
      4px -4px 0 #2b557c, 
      5px -5px 0 #2a5378, 
      6px -6px 0 #295074, 
      7px -7px 0 #274d71, 
      8px -8px 0 #264b6d, 
      9px -9px 0 #254869, 
      10px -10px 0 #234665, 
      11px -11px 0 #224361, 
      12px -12px 0 #21405e, 
      13px -13px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), 
      13px -13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Text</h1>
```

O `text-shadow` do exemplo anterior é, digamos, um pouco complicado. Mas vou tentar explicar melhor como ele funciona. Antes de enteder precisamos saber o que cada valor significa:

```
/* deslocamento-x | deslocamento-y | raio-de-desfoque | cor */
text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #2f5d87;
```

No exemplo passamos primeiro um valor de deslocamento horizontal de 1px e vertical de -1px, além disso um raio de desfoque de 0px (irrelevante) utilizando a cor #2f5d87. Só com isso teríamos o seguinte resultado:

```css
body {
  background-color: #880000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #2f5d87;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Text</h1>
```

Veja que o valor é quase inperceptível e portanto não daria um efeito de 3D. O que fizemos é aplicar uma série de efeitos encadeados ao `h1`. Veja como ficaria se adicionasse mais dois "efeitos".

```css
body {
  background-color: #880000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 
      1px -1px 0 #2f5d87,
      2px -2px 0 #2e5a83, 
      3px -3px 0 #2d5880;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Text</h1>
```

Veja como ele vai acumulando "as linhas de efeito" e se aproximando cada vez mais do efeito desejado.

**Referências:**

- [text-shadow - css - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

Comment: Achei a sua resposta muito boa, mas acho que ficaria melhor se explicasse o que são os valores usados no `text-shadow`

Comment: @Isac, dei uma melhorada, veja se está mais claro agora.

Comment: Ficou melhor, até os exemplos pequenos ajudam a perceber como funciona o efeito :)

Comment: Obrigado jovem, ficou muito bom o exemplo e a explicação!

Comment: Show, qualquer coisa só chamar hehe

Answer (score 4):

```css
h1 {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
  0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
  0 3px 0 #bbb,
  0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
  0 5px 0 #aaa,
  0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
  0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
  0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
  0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
  0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
  0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
  0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<h1>Teste</h1>
```

No caso acima, criei varias camadas do `text-shadow`, até chegar em algo próximo ao que espera.

Lembrando que o `text-shadow` é composto por 3 valores(X-offset, Y-offset, quantidade de blur e cor da sombra).

Comment: Valeu obrigado pela colaboração :)